# json get prolog predicate

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm tryung to create this predicate in prolog:

> The predicate `json_get/3` can be defined as: `json_get(JSON_obj, Fields, Result).` which is true when `Result` is recoverable by following
>         the chain of fields in `Fields` (a list) starting from `JSON_obj`. A field
>         represented by `N` (with `N` a major number o equal to 0) corresponds to
>         an index of a JSON array.

Please help me to understand to follow the chain of fields.

Thanks

edit1:

Of course, so json object looks like this '{"name" : "Aretha", "surname" : "Franklin"}'.
if i call json_parse predicate to this object prolog show me this

`json_obj([(”name”, ”Aretha”), (”surname”, ”Franklin”)])`, we call this obj `O`.

with `json_get` i need to extract from O the name in this way, `json_get(O, ["name"], R)`

edit2:

with someone's help this is the predicate now:

```
json_get(json_obj(JSON_obj), Field, Result) :-
    memberchk((Field,Result), JSON_obj).

json_get(JSON_obj, Fields, Result) :-
    maplist(json_get(JSON_obj), Fields, Result).
```

so now the problem is nested list.
For example with this input

```
json_parse('{"nome" : "Zaphod",
            "heads" : ["Head1", "Head2"]}', Z),
json_get(Z, ["heads", 1], R).
```

the output will should be `R = "Head2"` but the predicate doesn't extract the field and fail.

edit3:

this is the output of json_parse

```
json_obj([("nome", "Zaphod"),  ("heads", json_array(["Head1", "Head2"]))]).
```

Comment: Do you know what a "chain of fields" is? And do  you know what the representation of `JSON_obj` looks like? (And why is there an Aretha Franklin song playing in my head?)

Comment: Who knows why Aretha get interested in Prolog ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
json_get(json_obj(Obj),[F|Fs],Res) :-
  member((F,R),Obj),
  json_get(R,Fs,Res).
json_get(json_array(Is),[N|Fs],Res) :-
  nth1(N,Is,R),
  json_get(R,Fs,Res).
json_get(Res,[],Res).
```

This produces `Head1` not `Head2` in your 2nd example. Please explain how that is supposed to work, if you did not just make a typo. (If it is zero-based you can just change `nth1/3` to `nth0/3`.)

Comment: i only change nth1 with nth0, you are my savior thank you so much