# json get predicate (v2)

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

this is the predicatethat i use

```
json_get(json_obj(JSON_obj), Field, Result) :-
    memberchk((Field,Result), JSON_obj).

json_get(JSON_obj, Fields, Result) :-
        maplist(json_get(JSON_obj), Fields, Result).
```

so with this tests like this

```
json_parse('{"nome" : "Arthur", "cognome" : "Dent"}', O),
json_get(O, ["nome"], R).
```

are ok.

But the predicate not working with tests like this

```
json_parse('{"nome" : "Zaphod",
"heads" : ["Head1", "Head2"]}', Z),
json_get(Z, ["heads", 1], R).
```

how can i change the predicate to resolve this?

Thanks

Giuseppe

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this? Did you write the original predicate and understand how it works? Where is `json_obj/1` defined?

Comment: original predicate? what do you mean?

Comment: I'm referring  to  `json_get/3`. I just looked up your [prior question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153619/json-get-prolog-predicate). How is this  question different?

Comment: sorry but sincerly it's not different but nobody answer me in the old post and i have a short deadline to finish this

Comment: Where is `json_parse/2` defined?

Comment: json_parse is defined in the same project

Comment: I think the question was where for us to find it, so that we can run the code.

Comment: 1 mean the first item, "Head2"

Comment: the answer to the goal should be R = "Head2"

Comment: i tried many times but probably i made a mistake in the code

Comment: when i call json_parse and there is a json array, the array become a prolog list like this json_array(["head1", "head2"])

Comment: i see but i don't understand

Comment: the specification also says that a field represented by N (with N a major number o
equal to 0) corresponds to an index of a JSON array.

Comment: so i think i must use another predicate like json_get_1([Field|N], Result), no?